# How to run a shell script from an AppleScript?

Tags: macos, shell, shell-script, applescript

I am using a Mac running OSX Yosemite v.10.10.5.

When I try to run my shell script from my AppleScript, I get the following error message:

Error message at AppleScript Script Editor

```
error "sh: /Users/path/to/file/myShellScript.sh: Permission denied" number 126
```

myShellScript.sh

```
cd /Users/myusername/Git/myproject/
git remote remove origin
```

myAppleScript.applescript

```
do shell script "/Users/path/to/file/myShellScript.sh"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /Users/path/to/file/myShellScript.sh` ? Maybe the executable bit isn't set?

Answer (score 0):

Command Line

```
chmod a+x myShellScript.sh
```

Or

myAppleScript.applescript

```
do shell script "bash /Users/path/to/file/myShellScript.sh"
```

Plus: add shebang to top of shell script

myShellScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Note: If you want to use `sh` over `bash`, just substitute it in the command and the *shebang*.