# Run unix file with applescript with showing result

Tags: script, applescript

I use the following script https://github.com/chilcote/warranty
It works very fine with terminal.

Now I want to use it with applescript.
I think about "to do shell script" and that the script is in the directory "Resources"

I try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1066308/how-to-run-a-shell-script-from-an-applescript) solution, but it doesn't work.

My target: I want a apple script app what shows me the warranty status.

Thanks for your help.

my applescript code

```
set warranty to do shell script "bash " & POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/warranty.sh"
display dialog warranty
```

the error:

```
error "/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 43: 
Apple warranty estimation script.

This script estimates whether a given serial number is under warranty.
Input can be one or more given serial numbers, or a text file listing serials.
Output can be standard out or a CSV file.

usage: warranty [-h] [-v] [--quit-on-error] [-i INPUT] [-o OUTPUT] ...

positional arguments:
  serials

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         print output to console while writing to file
  --quit-on-error       if an error is encountered
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT
                        import serials from a file
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                        save output to a csv file

: command not found
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 45: import: command not found
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 46: import: command not found
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 47: import: command not found
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 48: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/dateutil
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 50: import: command not found
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 51: import: command not found
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 52: import: command not found
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 53: import: command not found
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 54: import: command not found
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 56: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/tz/Desktop/warranty: line 56: `def get_asd_plist():'" number 2
```

Comment: If your customer said "it doesn't work", what would your next question to them be? How can we possibly understand what doesn't work? Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1109712/edit) and provide extra information, such as any error messages, crashes etc. Then we can help :)

Comment: The warranty script is a **python** (.py) script, not a bash (.sh) script. The errors are coming from bash because your AppleScript is forcing warranty to run under bash.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a comment:

> The `warranty` script is a Python (`.py`) script, not a Bash (`.sh`) script. The errors are coming from bash because your AppleScript is forcing warranty to run under `bash`.

In other words, you want

```
set warranty to do shell script "python " & POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/warranty.sh"
```

(or possibly `"python3 "` if the script is a Python 3 script and you have `python` refer to Python version 2).

This is inferred from the error messages; perhaps the script is in yet another language. `import` and `from` are common keywords in Python scripts, so the inference is probably a good guess; but we can't tell for sure without seeing at least the beginning of the source of the `warranty` script.